# Salesforce Custom Button Signer Roles

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a custom button that implements a one-slick sign based on an existing template.I want to use the Custom Contact Role Map so that contact roles are automatically picked up from under the Account object and not opportunity. The code does not work.

Below is my code:

```
CRCL='AccountContactRoles,Email~Contact.Email;FirstName~Contact.FirstName LastName~Contact.LastName;
Role~Role,LoadDefaultContacts~0';
DST = 'CDC69B56-94D2-43F6-9994-2F4E13BBA3CB';
STB = '1';
```

Am I missing any steps. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

When was the last time you tested this?  There was a bug in the system that was causing this recently, but that bug was resolved and the fix pushed to DfS (DocuSign for Salesforce) 2-3 days ago.  Also, you need to be an *active* DfS user for this work, are you?

Comment: I have been testing this code for the last month or so. Yes, I am an active DfS user but on the sandbox environment. Can that be an issue?

Comment: So have you tested today then?  The fix has already been deployed (as of 3 days ago) so you shouldn't be getting this error anymore...

Comment: It's still not working. I have sent an email to our acct manager at DocuSign asking for help on this issue.